# Need help making Wine run correctly on my machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

I have been trying for multiple hours to get my wine installation to work, with no success.

I am currently on Ubuntu 22.04, with wine 6.0.3 installed (from ubuntu's official repos) Every time i try to open anything but Wine's built in programs, i keep getting either a

`"0024:err:mscoree:expect_no_runtimes Process exited with a Mono runtime loaded."` (on Celeste 1.4)

or a `"0024:err:process:exec_process L"Z:\\home\\anthony\\Documents\\Games\\The Binding of Isaac Rebirth Repentance v1.7.8a\\isaac-ng.exe" not supported on this system"`(on The Binding of Isaac)

I am fairly certain the programs themselves are not at fault, as i managed to make them run before i had to reinstall my OS for unrelated reasons.

I already googled those issues, and so have tried to

```
- switch WINEPREFIXES with different architectures (trying 32bit wine and 64bit wine)
- Reinstall wine through winehq's repos
- I even tried installing wine on a fresh install of Ubuntu, to make sure my OS wasn't at fault here
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem here ? Any attempt to help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :D

Addendum : So i listened to a comment and installed wine-mono, now im getting different errors

for celeste : `Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Celeste.Celeste' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: SDL2.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null) at (wrapper managed-to-native) SDL2.SDL.INTERNAL_SDL_GetPlatform() at SDL2.SDL.SDL_GetPlatform () [0x00000] in <4c19a1a736204d189ba94c3bc07cd4ac>:0  at Celeste.Celeste..cctor () [0x00006] in <d7b2abb405ec4c97954549f0a02e4a41>:0  --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Celeste.Celeste' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: SDL2.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null) at (wrapper managed-to-native) SDL2.SDL.INTERNAL_SDL_GetPlatform() at SDL2.SDL.SDL_GetPlatform () [0x00000] in <4c19a1a736204d189ba94c3bc07cd4ac>:0  at Celeste.Celeste..cctor () [0x00006] in <d7b2abb405ec4c97954549f0a02e4a41>:0`

for Isaac(when launched through ui) : `bad exe format for`

for Isaac(when launched through the Terminal) : `Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specified file. ShellExecuteEx failed: File not found.`

Comment: The `Mono runtime` in your error message suggests that it is not a "standard" Windows executable but is instead a .NET application that may require the [Mono runtime](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin) but you may actually have better luck with [Proton](https://www.protondb.com/app/250900) than WINE.

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [ask] and take the [tour], if you have not done so already. Also take a look at [example]. This is general information that you should keep in mind, when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the .NET Framework is missing and
needs to be installed.

The Wine version of .Net is
[Mono](https://wiki.winehq.org/Mono),
described as:

> Mono is an open-source and cross-platform implementation of the .NET Framework. Wine can use a Windows build of Mono to run .NET applications.

The package is called `wine-mono` and may exist in your repository.

If it doesn't exist, you may find the install
[wine-mono.msi](https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/)
in the official WineHQ site.
But in this case, you might as well install the latest stable version
of Wine from
[WineHQ](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: Thank you ! So i installed mono and now im getting different errors : (ill edit them in my original pose because i need more characters)